# error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character `X' in: -Xlinker

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, libtool-xcode

I am receiving the following error when trying to build the app my developer sent me. I need to compile a successful build. Is there anyone that knows how to resolve this? I am fairly new to xcode.

```
Libtool /Users/zlabs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Swifty_Box-cneiigzloqreiccoaycwwtmcvygu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Swifty\ Box.app/Swifty\ Box normal x86_64
cd "/Users/zlabs/Desktop/SwiftyBox (50502)"
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only x86_64 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/zyelabs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Swifty_Box-cneiigzloqreiccoaycwwtmcvygu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/zlabs/Desktop/SwiftyBox\ (50502)/Swifty -LBox/Ads/TapItSDK/extras -LBird/Ads/TapItSDK -LBox/Ads/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk -filelist /Users/zlabs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Swifty_Boxw-cneiigzloqreiccoaycwwtmcvygu/Build/Intermediates/Swifty\ Box.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Swifty\ Box.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Swifty\ Box.LinkFileList -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/zlabs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Swifty_Box-cneiigzloqreiccoaycwwtmcvygu/Build/Intermediates/Swifty\ Bird.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Swifty\ Box.build/Swifty\ Box.xcent -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreLocation -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MessageUI -framework MediaPlayer -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreData -framework AddressBookUI -framework AddressBook -framework EventKitUI -framework EventKit -framework PassKit -framework iAd -framework CoreMedia -framework Accelerate -framework AVFoundation -framework Security -framework OpenAL -framework CFNetwork -framework MobileCoreServices -framework GameKit -framework AdSupport -framework Accounts -framework Social -framework StoreKit -lGoogleAdMobAds -lObjectiveChipmunk -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreText -framework OpenGLES -framework Foundation -o /Users/zlabs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Swifty_Bird-cneiigzloqreiccoaycwwtmcvygu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Swifty\ Box.app/Swifty\ Box
error:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character `X' in: -Xlinker

Usage:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static [-] file [...] [-filelist listfile[,dirname]] [-arch_only arch] [-sacLT]
Usage: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -dynamic [-] file [...] [-filelist listfile[,dirname]] [-arch_only arch] [-o output] [-install_name name] [-compatibility_version #] [-current_version #] [-seg1addr 0x#] [-segs_read_only_addr 0x#] [-segs_read_write_addr 0x#] [-seg_addr_table <filename>] [-seg_addr_table_filename <file_system_path>] [-all_load] [-noall_load]
```

Comment: I think you need to show which lines of code generated the error in order for someone to be able to help you.

Comment: My bad, I have updated the posted with the full error message in xcode.

Comment: This perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693769/xcode5-simulator-unknown-option-character-x-in-xlinker