# Swift is not supported for static libraries

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I try create own CocoaPods. First It can build with out error but after I add some file in "PodName/Classes" that will have Error "Swift is not supported for static libraries." How to fix it?
In the past I do it same but It work until today.

---

OK I can fix it when I add new file I change targets to myFramework (normally add to example)
[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020783/how-to-distribute-swift-library-without-exposing-the-source-code

Comment: I change targets file to myFramework can fix it.   http://www.pickygame.com/Download/sample/FixSwiftStaticLibraries.png

Comment: Awww! Thank you!!!!