# How to Create Swift Framework without exposing the source code in all scenario?

Tags: ios, swift, security, frameworks

I created a custom `FrameWork` in `Swift 3` and I Distribute this framework using `CocoaPods`. Its working fine

**My problem is**, I use this `FrameWork` in Third party Application, And made a crash in the framework for manual testing. At the time of crash my `FrameWork` code is expose in that Third party Application. Its created security issue for my FrameWork.

Any suggestion to stop exposing of my `FrameWork` source code in any other Application in all scenario?

> Note :
>   I made only one class as `Open` for accessing FrameWork.

Comment: Hi, I'm interested by your solution. I have a Swift 3 Framework too and I'd like to protect my source code. How did you do that ? What are you calling "Open" ? (You means "Public", isn't it ?). Thanks !

Comment: @BenjaminGoutfer Am made one class as open for access the framework for any other application. In that class make the Methods Open which are using outside the framework.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to distribute Swift Library without exposing the source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020783/how-to-distribute-swift-library-without-exposing-the-source-code)