# Apple Mach-O Librarian error for swift static lib using cocoapods

Tags: xcode6, cocoapods

I have one public repository https://github.com/SSamanta/SSHTTPClient. This code has been written in swift and I created **podspec** file for that.

In another sample project while I am trying to use that lib as pod that but I am getting below compilation error in Xcode 6.2 beta 2.

```
error: /Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character `X' in: -Xlinker
```

But When I am using another repo https://github.com/SSamanta/SSRestClient which is written in Objective C then it's working correctly.

Are there any problem in cocoapods or static lib in swift?

Comment: Xcode does not support building static libraries that include Swift code. Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041962/static-linking-with-swift-xcode6-beta