# Link error: unknown option character `X' in: -Xlinker

Tags: ios, xcode, libtool-xcode

The following linker command results in the error below.  This is building for the simulator target in XCode for iOS.  it's unclear what is even providing the Xlinker arguments via XCode.  Any thoughts on how i might pursue a solution here?

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool
>   -static -arch_only i386 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk
>   -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -o libxxx.a
>
> error:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
>   unknown option character `X' in: -Xlinker

(note: this error seemingly happens out of nowhere.  the same project file was building ok days ago).

Comment: I started seeing this error after installing the XCode 6 GM.

Comment: how did you solve it?

Comment: this may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693769/xcode5-simulator-unknown-option-character-x-in-xlinker

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `use_frameworks!` to your Podfile and run `pod install`.

That should resolve the issue.