# bug compiling alamofire - unknown option character `X' in: -Xlinker

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alamofire

Trying to add alamofire to a project using cocoapods.
Xcode version: Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a)

Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'OAuth.io'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.1'
```

Here's the error:

```
Libtool /Users/tony/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candytone-aynufizixrzmtwgatrvrjynlonxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods-Alamofire.a normal x86_64
    cd /Users/tony/src/candytone-ios/Candytone/Pods
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only x86_64 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -L/Users/tony/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candytone-aynufizixrzmtwgatrvrjynlonxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/tony/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candytone-aynufizixrzmtwgatrvrjynlonxv/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-Alamofire.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Pods-Alamofire.LinkFileList -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/tony/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candytone-aynufizixrzmtwgatrvrjynlonxv/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-Alamofire.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Pods_Alamofire.swiftmodule -framework Foundation -o /Users/tony/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candytone-aynufizixrzmtwgatrvrjynlonxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods-Alamofire.a

error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character `X' in: -Xlinker
Usage: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static [-] file [...] [-filelist listfile[,dirname]] [-arch_only arch] [-sacLT] [-no_warning_for_no_symbols]
Usage: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -dynamic [-] file [...] [-filelist listfile[,dirname]] [-arch_only arch] [-o output] [-install_name name] [-compatibility_version #] [-current_version #] [-seg1addr 0x#] [-segs_read_only_addr 0x#] [-segs_read_write_addr 0x#] [-seg_addr_table <filename>] [-seg_addr_table_filename <file_system_path>] [-all_load] [-noall_load]
```

Comment: Follow this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693769/xcode5-simulator-unknown-option-character-x-in-xlinker

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue was solved by upgrading to Cocoapods 0.36beta.

```
gem install cocoapods --pre
```

I also had to remove the old version.

```
gem uninstall cocoapods
```

Comment: Thanks for that! It helped me. I would add that in my case I had to delete pod from my project and reinstall it

Comment: I had to add `use_frameworks!`  to my podfile - otherwise solution works.

Comment: Update: cocoapods 0.36 is released so just do `gem install cocoapods` and add `use_frameworks!` in your `Podfile`. Warning: not 100% current pods support framework - at the time being I would stay apart from swift pods.

Comment: Follow this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693769/xcode5-simulator-unknown-option-character-x-in-xlinker